# Why does my loop breaks the css below?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, loop

```
            <?php
                    /**
                     * My Orders - Deprecated
                     *
                     * @deprecated 2.6.0 this template file is no longer used. My Account shortcode uses orders.php.
                     * @package WooCommerce\Templates
                     */

                    defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

                    $customer_orders = get_posts(
                        apply_filters(
                            'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query',
                            array(
                                'numberposts' => $order_count,
                                'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
                                'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
                                'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
                                'post_status' => 'wc-processing',
                            )
                        )
                    );

                    if ( $customer_orders ) : ?>
        <div id="active-orders" class="ras__item">
          <p class="title">Активные заказы</p>
          <div class="ras-table">
            <div class="ras-thead">
              <div class="ras-tr">
                <span class="ras-td">Дата заказа</span>
                <span class="ras-td">Номер заказа</span>
                <span class="ras-td">Статус</span>
                <span class="ras-td">Доставка</span>
                <span class="ras-td">Сумма</span>
                <span class="ras-td">Залог</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ras-tbody">
            <?php
                                    foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) :
                                        $order      = wc_get_order( $customer_order ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                                        $item_count = $order->get_item_count();
                                        ?>
              <div class="ras-tr">
                <span class="ras-td"><time datetime="<?php echo esc_attr( $order->get_date_created()->date( 'c' ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ); ?></time></span>
                <span class="ras-td"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>"><?php echo _x( '#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce' ) . $order->get_order_number(); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></a></span>
                <span class="ras-td status orange"><?php echo esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) ); ?></span>
                <span class="ras-td"><?echo $order->get_shipping_method();?></span>
                <span class="ras-td"><?php
                     /* translators: 1: formatted order total 2: total order items */
                     printf( _n( '%1$s', '%1$s', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                     ?></span>
                <span class="ras-td"><?php printf( get_field( 'zalog', $order_id ) ); ?></span>
                <span class="ras-td read-more">
                    <?php
                   $actions = wc_get_account_orders_actions( $order );

                   if ( ! empty( $actions ) ) {
                   foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) { // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                   echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html('Подробнее') . '</a>';
                        }
                   }
                   ?>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div id="archive-orders" class="ras__item">
          <p class="title">Архив заказов</p>
          <div class="ras-table">
            <div class="ras-thead">
              <div class="ras-tr">
                <span class="ras-td">Дата заказа</span>
                <span class="ras-td">Номер заказа</span>
                <span class="ras-td">Статус</span>
                <span class="ras-td">Доставка</span>
                <span class="ras-td">Сумма</span>
                <span class="ras-td">Залог</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ras-tbody">
              <div class="ras-tr">
                <span class="ras-td">02.10.2020</span>
                <span class="ras-td">#1001005</span>
                <span class="ras-td status">Выполнен</span>
                <span class="ras-td">Самовывоз</span>
                <span class="ras-td">20 000 ₽</span>
                <span class="ras-td">5 000 ₽</span>
                <span class="ras-td read-more">
                  <a href="">Подробнее</a>
                </span>
              </div>
              <div class="ras-tr">
                <span class="ras-td">02.10.2020</span>
                <span class="ras-td">#1001005</span>
                <span class="ras-td status">Выполнен</span>
                <span class="ras-td">Самовывоз</span>
                <span class="ras-td">20 000 ₽</span>
                <span class="ras-td">5 000 ₽</span>
                <span class="ras-td read-more">
                  <a href="">Подробнее</a>
                </span>
              </div>
              <div class="ras-tr">
                <span class="ras-td">02.10.2020</span>
                <span class="ras-td">#1001005</span>
                <span class="ras-td status">Выполнен</span>
                <span class="ras-td">Самовывоз</span>
                <span class="ras-td">20 000 ₽</span>
                <span class="ras-td">5 000 ₽</span>
                <span class="ras-td read-more">
                  <a href="">Подробнее</a>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

The CSS is broken outside of the loop

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an extra closing div tag and section tag. Add html comments to the closing div tags to keep track of which div they belong to like this:

```
                </div> <!-- /.ras-tr -->
            </div> <!-- /.ras-tbody -->
        </div> <!-- /.ras-table -->
    </div> <!-- /.ras-item -->
```

Also verify that there isn't another template that might have the extra opening section and div tag.

Comment: Thank you! It worked.